# Wildcard App ID issue with Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode

I used to have a provisioning profile with an associated wildcard app ID (*) to sign a bunch of apps for customers. Each explicit app ID is declared into the Bundle ID field in the Xcode project. The problem is that each app uses *Wireless Accessory Configuration* capability. As reported by Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1713/_index.html),

> Because an App ID specifies a unique configuration of entitlements, Wildcard App IDs are for use with code signing all apps that do not enable app-specific capabilities.

Until Xcode 7.3 this wasn't a big deal, it always worked. After updating to the last public beta of Xcode 8.0, I'm not able to code sign my apps anymore using the wildcard app ID associated to my provisioning profile and I can't add explicit app IDs to it because they are already managed by customers. When I try using the new automatic code signing feature, it tells me that the app ID that I suggested in the Bundle ID field of my Xcode project cannot be registered to my development team (of course not!, because it belongs to the customer's team which I'm not a member of).

If I click in the Info disclosure button next to the Xcode managed profile, the only issue that I can see is that the *Wireless Accessory Configuration* capability is missing

[image]

So, could I ask the customer to add this capability to the explicit app ID in order to solve this issue?

If I try to code sign the app directly in the Build Settings using the old method with my provisioning profile (which I regenerated again), I always obtain the following issue:

> "App" isn't code signed but requires entitlements. It is not possible to add entitlements to a binary without signing it.
>
> Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

Could someone please help me addressing this problem? I'm stuck since days.

Comment: Did you try deselecting automatic manage profiles?

Comment: @rptwsthi I did. As I've already said, I set the provisioning profile in the Build Settings as I did with Xcode 7.3, but it seems not to work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of possible solutions:

1. Have them add you as a member to their development team.
2. Make the bundle ID dependent on the the build configuration. Then you can register an App ID yourself and add the capability.
3. Make the entitlements.plist-file dependent on the configuration. Have a separate entitlements.plist-file without the capability for your development and testing.

Comment: I chose solution #2, actually is the easiest way and I managed to solve the problem. Thank you.

Another question: should I ask customers to add the capability to their own app IDs anyway? I think that would simplify things when they create their own distribution provisioning profile for app deployment. What would you suggest?